# Camera orientation change is too slow

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview

I have a `DrawerLayout` which contains a `FrameLayout` and `ListView` in my app, I have to show the camera preview in the `FrameLayout`, I've done that fine (as following code) and the camera works correctly. `The problem` is when moving from portrait orientation to (right-Landscape orientation or left-landscape orientation), or vice versa, it take the mobile a long time to make changes, the problem does not appear when moving from right-Landscape orientation or left-landscape orientation or vice versa.
How I could make this operation is as fast as I can.